# How to concatenate two strings in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I want to concatenate the words "dummy's" and "dock".

How can I concatenate them in SQL Server 2005?  Does it support double quotes?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate results, or input/variables?  Have any locale requirements?

Comment: For basics like this, I would recommend you consult the **SQL Server Books Online** - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @COMBINED_STRINGS AS VARCHAR(50); -- Allocate just enough length for the two strings.

SET @COMBINED_STRINGS = 'rupesh''s' + 'malviya';
SELECT @COMBINED_STRINGS; -- Print your combined strings.
```

Or you can put your strings into variables. Such that:

```
DECLARE @COMBINED_STRINGS AS VARCHAR(50),
        @STRING1 AS VARCHAR(20),
        @STRING2 AS VARCHAR(20);

SET @STRING1 = 'rupesh''s';
SET @STRING2 = 'malviya';
SET @COMBINED_STRINGS = @STRING1 + @STRING2;

SELECT @COMBINED_STRINGS;
```

**Output:**

`rupesh'smalviya`

Just add a space in your string as a separator.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet it looks as if the extra ' ' is an escape sequence to allow the ' in the final string.

Answer (score 15):

so if you have a table with a row like:

```
firstname lastname
Bill      smith
```

you can do something like

```
select firstname + ' ' + lastname from thetable
```

and you will get "Bill Smith"

Answer (score 8):

Try something like

```
SELECT 'rupesh''s' + 'malviya'
```

[+ (String Concatenation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862(SQL.80).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate two strings in 2008 or prior:

```
SELECT ISNULL(FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(SurName, '')
```

good to use ISNULL because "String + NULL" will give you a NULL only

One more thing: Make sure you are concatenating strings otherwise use a CAST operator:

```
SELECT 2 + 3
```

Will give 5

```
SELECT '2' + '3'
```

Will give 23

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @COMBINED_STRINGS AS VARCHAR(50),
        @STRING1 AS VARCHAR(20),
        @STRING2 AS VARCHAR(20);

SET @STRING1 = 'rupesh''s';
SET @STRING2 = 'malviya';
SET @COMBINED_STRINGS = @STRING1 + @STRING2;

SELECT @COMBINED_STRINGS;

SELECT '2' + '3';
```

I typed this in a sql file named TEST.sql and I run it. I got the following out put.

```
+-------------------+
| @COMBINED_STRINGS |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------+
| '2' + '3' |
+-----------+
|         5 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

After looking into this issue a bit more I found the best and sure sort way for string concatenation in SQL is by using CONCAT method.
So I made the following changes in the same file.

```
#DECLARE @COMBINED_STRINGS AS VARCHAR(50),
 #       @STRING1 AS VARCHAR(20),
 #       @STRING2 AS VARCHAR(20);

SET @STRING1 = 'rupesh''s';
SET @STRING2 = 'malviya';
#SET @COMBINED_STRINGS = @STRING1 + @STRING2;
SET @COMBINED_STRINGS = (SELECT CONCAT(@STRING1, @STRING2));

SELECT @COMBINED_STRINGS;

#SELECT '2' + '3';
SELECT CONCAT('2','3');
```

and after executing the file this was the output.

```
+-------------------+
| @COMBINED_STRINGS |
+-------------------+
| rupesh'smalviya   |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------------+
| CONCAT('2','3') |
+-----------------+
| 23              |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

SQL version I am using is: 14.14

Comment: OP specifically identified SQL Server 2005, and while your answer is elegant, CONCAT was not added as a function in SQL server until maybe version 2012, at the very least - it was WAY after 2005.  SO, in other words, CONCAT will not work for the version OP is running.

Answer (score 0):

I got a easy solution which will select from database table and let you do easily.

```
SELECT b.FirstName + b.LastName FROM tbl_Users b WHERE b.Id='11'
```

You can easily add a space  there if you try

```
SELECT b.FirstName +' '+ b.LastName FROM Users b WHERE b.Id='23'
```

Here you can combine as much as your table have.