# What is the equivalent of Conc() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I am translating MS Access queries to SQL Server.

I came across

```
SELECT 
    [R1EQ].CompanyId, [R1EQ].DateOnFile, 
    R1EQ.service_name, 
    Conc("DSPs", "ISPID", [ISPID], "R1EQ", "DateOnFile", [DateOnFile]) AS ColName
```

Can someone please tell me what is the equivalent of the `conc` function in SQL Server?

Comment: Tried Concatenate()? And concat()?   You might need to cast columns to get consistent datatype

Comment: Start by telling us what it is in Access. It sounds like a user-defined function (it's not standard), and you have those too in SQL server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two strings in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048955/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

Is seems you are looking for `concat()` function :

```
SELECT [R1EQ].CompanyId, [R1EQ].DateOnFile, R1EQ.service_name, 
       CONCAT('DSPs', 'ISPID', [ISPID], 'R1EQ', 'DateOnFile', DateOnFile) AS ColName
. . .
```

However, this would required at least SQL Server 2012+ for earlier you have to use `+` operator

```
SELECT [R1EQ].CompanyId, [R1EQ].DateOnFile, R1EQ.service_name, 
       ('DSPs'+'ISPID'+ CAST([ISPID] AS VARCHAR(255) +'R1EQ' + 
        'DateOnFile', CAST(DateOnFile AS VARCHAR(255)
       ) AS ColName
 . . .
```

Comment: `conc` is not a built-in concatenation function in Access. This is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the concatenation operator in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    [R1EQ].CompanyId,
    [R1EQ].DateOnFile,
    R1EQ.service_name,
    "DSPs" + "ISPID" + [ISPID] + "R1EQ" + "DateOnFile" + [DateOnFile] AS ColName
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: `conc` is not a built-in concatenation function in Access. This is just a guess.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth No it's not, you'd use `&` I think.  But, the OP seems to want to concatenate, so...

Comment: why does it seem that way? Are you just guessing it by the function name? Writing a user-defined function that only concatenates in Access would be ridiculously inefficient, so I'd guess it does something more/else.

Answer (score 0):

`CONC()` is not a built-in function in MS Access.  It can do anything, but references on the web suggest that it concatenates strings.  Note that it might do more, such as inserting delimiter characters.

The equivalent oeprator SQL Server is `+`, but you need to be very careful.  All the arguments need to be strings.  So, you will probably need to convert them.  The place to start is:

```
SELECT [R1EQ].CompanyId, [R1EQ].DateOnFile, 
       R1EQ.service_name, 
      ('DSPs' + 'ISPID' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), ISPID), +
       'R1EQ' + 'DateOnFile',
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(2555), DateOnFile)  -- you might want a format
      ) AS ColName
```